# Best practice to create factory where there is some differences in implementation classes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, architecture, factory-pattern

I have the following Interface

```
public interface CityValidator {
    public vaalidateChecksum(String cityCode); 
    public vaalidateChecksum(String cityCode, String postIndex); 
}
```

And I have two different implementations In one of them I only need vaalidateChecksum(String cityCode) and don't need vaalidateChecksum(String cityCode, String postIndex) at all, in other, I need vise versa.

```
public class KyivCityValidator implements CityValidator{

    public vaalidateChecksum(String cityCode) {
         validateCheeksum(cityCode, null)
    }

    public vaalidateChecksum(String cityCode, String postIndex) {
         // some code
    } 

}

public class LondonCityValidator implements CityValidator{

    public vaalidateChecksum(String cityCode) {
        // I don't need implementation of this method at all
    }
    public vaalidateChecksum(String cityCode, String postIndex) { 
     // some code
    }
}
```

Then I want to have a factory that returns me Validator and I can use one of the above-mentioned methods that I want. Example:

```
CityValidator kyivValidator = CityValidatorFactory.getValidator(new Kyiv());
kyivValidator.vaalidateChecksum(cityCode);

CityValidator londonValidator = CityValidatorFactory.getValidator(new London());
londonValidator.vaalidateChecksum(cityCode, postalIndex);
```

But what is the best case for implementation of

```
 public vaalidateChecksum(String cityCode) {
    // I don't need implementation of this method at all
 }
```

in LondonCityValidator class in the case when I don't need it at all.

I thought about just throwing a UnsopportedMethodException into them but I am not sure that is a good decision.

What is the best solution to this issue?

Comment: Why not just have one validator where you pass in the name of the city as a String and implement both methods?  That way, your factory still decides which validator method to use.  You could have two factory methods in your factory class, one for London and one for Kyiv.

Comment: The thing is there is no implementation for London only by city code then I can't even implement this method at all, there is only validation by code+index where for Kyiv validation performs only by city code but not code+index. It's two different formulas for the validation algorithm of both cities.